# cordova ios cocoapods requirement not met

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods

I am trying to run build default cordova app "hello" but when do do `cordova requirements` the message contains the following:

```
Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed [object Object]
ios-deploy: not installed
ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.9.2 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path, or do 'npm install -g ios-deploy'
CocoaPods: not installed
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

There are a number of things I have not yet installed such as ios-deploy however cocoapods I already have yet cordova claims otherwise. I tried reinstall cocoapods via brew and got this:

```
➜  ~ brew install cocoapods
Warning: cocoapods 1.4.0 is already installed
```

I'm not sure why this is happening but I think it might have to do with the fact that I have to do all my commands using sudo, for example to list the requirements I needed to do `sudo cordova requirements` rather than just `cordova requirements`. Moreover cordova seems to mention this, in the output of requirements (see above) it says `You cannot run CocoaPods as root`.

Thanks for the help

Comment: try `gem install cocoapods`?

Comment: I installed using gem but it still gives the same error

Comment: I just re-read the error. `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)`

Are you running with `sudo`?